# Use of J2ME Choice Group Control in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

i have developed an application in J2ME.  J2ME standard controls has been used across the application.
its working fine on Nokia Devices.

i want to convert this application in Blackberry.
i have created MIDlet project in BlackBerry IDE.

the problem is: J2ME standard choice group control is not working in Blackberry.

What should be the alternative of choice group control in Blackberry? 
or 
How it will work in Blackberry?

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? Afaik standard J2ME should run on Blackberry devices. (Well, prior to Blackberry 10 OS anyway). But it's not unusual that J2ME code behaves differently across devices. Maybe you just need to tweak your code a bit to get it working on Blackberry.

Comment: ok Thanks for your quick answer. i have solved on myself. i was using `ChoiceGroup serviceStatus = new ChoiceGroup("Double Number Status", Choice.EXCLUSIVE);`. i just change in ChoiceGroup type. `Choice.Exclusive` to `Choice.POPUP`. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem on behalf of me.
I just changed the `ChoiceGroup` Type.
Now I use `Choice.POPUP` .its working fine.